Old Iteration of index.html Loading Over New
Every time I try to redeploy to my site and make changes to my index.html it shows the new version for a split second and then loads the old version. Here is a list of things I have done to fix it but to no avail:
cleared the browser cache
done all if the service worker stuff (restarting service workers or preventing them from working on index.html)
made sure to have no caching in my server.js
I don't use a CDN
I don't have any volumes on my droplet
implemented nginx specifically to have it prevent caching
deleted all old docker images on my droplet to give it a pure restart
In the browser developer tools it says it is only requesting one index.html (which is just the ip)
I am kind of out of my element here and am trying to figure out what I don't know.
Also what further context could I add that would help find a solution?
Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

can you create a small index.html that does the same behavior and that you can include in your posted question? As a first start, remove most of the body of the page while keeping all of the header. Also is there any javascript that is running at the time the page is loaded? Also do you have a copy of the old index.html file located somewhere on your server?
